# the image of finite blaschke product

Tags: complex-analysis

I'd like to show that the image of finite blaschke product from the unit disc on $\mathbb{C}$ onto inself.

I'm sure that this mapping is continuous and the domain, i.e., the unit disc is compact and connected, so is the image under this mapping.

And I know that the unit circle is mapped onto itself and that there is some point in the domain which is mapped to $0$.

But I cannot fill in the gap between 0 and the unit circle.

Could you give me a little hint? I'd like to prove this with my own.

Thank you for your kind answer in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $f$ be a finite Blascke product. If some $a\in \mathbb D$ is not in the range of $f,$ consider $\phi_a\circ f.$

Comment: What is $\phi_a$?

Comment: Or use the fundamental theorem of algebra and show that if $B$ is a finite blaschke product of order n and $|\lambda|<1$ or $|\lambda|=1$ the equation $B(z)=\lambda$ becomes a polynomial equation of degree precisely $n$ when clearing denominators and hence it has $n$ roots counted with multiplicity; but by topological reasons, the roots when $\lambda$ is inside the disc are also inside the disc and same on the unit circle; with a little more work one can show that on the unit circle the roots are actually distinct

Comment: $\phi_a(z) = \dfrac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}.$

Comment: @Conrad Why is the surjectiveness of the mapping related to the distinctness of the roots on unit circle ?

Comment: It is not related directly of course but it is one of the more striking properties of finite blaschke products

Comment: @zhw. Let me explain what I'm thinking. By assumption, the new defined function cannot assume 0. and it is a nonconstant analytic on the unit disc. Since the unit disc is compact and the new function is continuous, it has to have a minimum modulus. But on the boundary, its modulus is 1. And inside the boundary, it could assume a smaller modulus than 1. So this function has to assume its minimum modulus inside the circle. If this is so, the new function  should be a constant, which contradicts the assumption. Is it right? If not, could you point out where I failed?

Comment: Right, an analytic function that is nowhere $0$ cannot have a minimum modulus inside a connected domain unless it is constant.